# Can 't create extesion method for LINQ to Entities link DeleteAllOnSubmit() in LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Since there is no `DeleteAllOnSubmit()` method  for LINQ to Entities. So I myself create it and named for `DeleteAllObjects` as following code.

```
public static void DeleleAllObjects<TEntity>(this ObjectSet<TEntity> objectSet, TEntity[] objects)
{
    foreach(var o in objects)
    {
        objectSet.DeleteObject(o);
    }
}
```

However the code I write fail on compile and get the error message:

> The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as
>   parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method

I think use foreach with DeleteObject all the time is not a good idea for delete collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  The method needs to be a generic, `TEntity` is simply the placeholder for the type.

```
public static void DeleteAllObjects<TEntity>( this ObjectSet<TEntity> objectSet,
                                              IEnumerable<TEntity> objects)
    where TEntity : class
{

   foreach(var o in objects)
   {
      objectSet.DeleteObject(o);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank tvanfosson for your suggestion. I've tried it and got the same error. The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<TEntity>'

Comment: You need a class constraint on the type parameter.

Comment: @embarus -- @Craig is right.  I omitted the generic constraint.  I've updated.

Comment: Thank you very much, tvanfosson. This help me a lot. :)

Comment: @embarus -- glad to be of help.  Since you're new I thought I'd let you know that the way the system works is that you vote up (using the arrows next to the answer score) answers that are helpful and accept (using the check mark) the answer that solves your problem.  The more you use the system the better off you'll be if you use the voting mechanisms to reward those who help you.