# Entity Framework Delete All on Submit

Tags: entity-framework

In LINQ to SQL, I could do:

```
context.User_Roles.DeleteAllOnSubmit(context.User_Roles.Where(ur => ur.UserId == user.UserId));
```

Whats the equivalent to this for entity framework?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869209/bulk-deleting-in-linq-to-entities?lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Femaref has the right idea, but for a true analog to L2E's `DeleteAllOnSubmit`, you'll want your extension method to make a copy of the entities being deleted before enumerating so that you don't get "collection modified while enumerating" exceptions.

```
public static void DeleteAllObjects<TEntity>(this ObjectSet<TEntity> set, IEnumerable<TEntity> data) where TEntity : class {
    foreach(var entity in data.ToList()) //data.ToList() makes a copy of data for safe enumeration
        set.DeleteObject(entity);
}
```

Comment: This was my problem with the accepted answer.  Is there a more efficient way than pulling the whole set into memory though?

Comment: @Eric - not out-of-the-box, you'd need to resort to a custom solution, perhaps using inline SQL someway, but I haven't tried anything like that

Comment: Or just iterate through the data using: `for (int i = data.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--) set.DeleteObject(data.ElementAt(i));`

Answer (score 24):

```
foreach(var entity in context.User_Roles.Where(ur => ur.UserId == user.UserId))
{
  context.User_Roles.DeleteObject(entity);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Of course, you can write an extension method, which would encapsulate this.

This would be something like this:

```
public static void DeleteObjects<TEntity> (this ObjectSet<TEntity> set, IEnumerable<TEntity> data) where TEntity : class
{
  foreach(var entity in data)
    set.DeleteObject(entity);
}
```

Called like:

```
context.User_Roles.DeleteObjects(context.User_Roles.Where(ur => ur.UserId == user.UserId))
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You may run into this issue using this method, this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742340/183174

Comment: @nomad311 what exacly is the issue that you mention?

Comment: The title of that question `Can 't create extesion method for LINQ to Enitities link DeleteAllOnSubmit() in LINQ to SQL` is the error message you would get if you ran into the that issue.

Comment: `DeleteObjects` needs to be static and `TEntity` needs to be constrained to a class: `public static void DeleteObjects<TEntity>(this ObjectSet<TEntity> set, IEnumerable<TEntity> data) where TEntity : class`

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(var entity in context.User_Roles.Where(ur => ur.UserId == user.UserId))
{
  context.User_Roles.DeleteObject(entity);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

of course, this solution can work. But, it is the most inefficient solution.
This solution will generate one delete SQL command for each record (entity).
Imaging that you want to delete all data before year 2000 . there are more than 1,000,000 records in the database. If delete these objects in this way, more than 1,000,000 SQL commands will be sent to the server, it is a unnecessary big waste.
What

Comment: Your answer looks incomplete. What would be an alternative, more efficient approach?

Comment: I didn't read your code carefullly. but, why do you say "delete ALL on submit"? what do you mean "ALL" here?<br/>if you want to delete all data in a table over than 2000 rows or even more, you must use delete statement rather than the answers given above. for consideration of efficiency.

Comment: It's unlikely that someone will have so many users with the same UserId (It should be a Primary Key and there would be only one user with this UserId). I agree however, that for a large number of entities there are faster solutions, like **ExecuteStoreCommand** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869209/bulk-deleting-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: yes, you are right. I was disguided by the title: delete ALL on submit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no RemoveAll equivalent in Entity Framework, so you can load entities in memory and remove them one by one using DeleteObject method.

You can use Linq : context.MyEntitie.RemoveAll(context.MyEntitie);

Answer (score 0):

use [EntityFramework.Extensions](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)
1) First install EntityFramework.Extensions using NuGet

2) Here is the code similar to Linq2Sql's DeleteAllOnSubmit():

```
using EntityFramework.Extensions;

....
public void DeleteAllUsers(User_Role user){
   context.User_Roles.Delete(ur => ur.UserId == user.UserId);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
...
```

Comment: if you pass an argument like ur.UserID == user.UserId as bool, why dont you just pass a 'true' value ;-)

So much cleaner, anyway, that will be always an antipattern.